# Controls inside of a class library not responding properly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF application and recently I moved it to a class library project so it could be injected into another process.

I have succeeded in this and the WPF application loads up correctly and works correctly but some of the controls don't act as they should. My 'exe' version of the project contains exactly the same MainWindow.xaml , but here the controls respond as they should.

When I say they 'don't respond properly', I mean that although the controls do work, they often get stuck and I need to move the window.

However, if I create another project and reference the controls in the class library I don't have any problems loading the window. The problem arises as the code is injected into another process, and I'm wondering whether there could be some window focus problem or similar. For example, if I expand my tree view (this behavior only happens when using the expand 'button' on the left of the tree view item), anywhere I click afterwards causes the tree view to expand a collapse continuously, until I move the window.

I did try to read a bit into how WPF + HWnd works, but I still don't understand this behavior and if anyone could explain it I would be very grateful!

Edit:

I am not using a a WPF theme, and the correct version of .Net is targeted (3.5).

Comment: This sounds strange to me. I am guessing there is something specific to your setup that is causing this issue because referencing controls in a class library is extremely common and you should see no behavioral differences from not placing them directly in the EXE project.

Comment: If I create another project and reference the controls in the class library I don't have any problems loading the window. However, the problem arises as the code is injected into another process, and I'm wondering whether there could be some window focus problem or similar. For example, if I expand my tree view (this behavior only happens when using the expand 'button' on the left of the tree view item), anywhere I click afterwards causes the tree view to expand a collapse continuously, until I move the window.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, WPF is part of the .net framework. The .net Framework versions are 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and 4.0.

The nuisance you're experiencing sometimes is cause by selecting the wrong version of .net for attributes used in you code. I would check there first.

Comment: This is not the problem, I have double checked the .net Framework version, and it is all as it should be (target framework 3.5). I think the problem is more due to the fact that the code is injected into a target process